# change descriptor Size in SURF

Tags: opencv, surf, feature-descriptor

I am trying to change the descriptor Size to be 128 instead of 64 in openCV

does anybody know how can I change it

here is a part of my code

```
{    
    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 ); // try to get most number of  keypoint for matching 
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;
detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
detector.detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor ;
Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
extractor.compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Extended parameter is responsible for the size of descriptors. Set it to 1(true) and 128-element descriptors should be calculated.

```
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor(hessianThreshold, nOctaves, nOctaveLayers,  
                                                        ***extended***, upright);
```

Comment: I already did this in "SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 );" do I need to do it again for the extractor ?